# Exclude folder from redirects and serve it as landing page (htaccess)

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

I'll try to explain myself as clearly as possible.

I have a webpack/vanillaJS website hosted on the root of this host. Among the files, I have a lonely "landing-page" folder. The struct is basically :

```
root/
├── index.php
├── .htaccess
├── other.build.files
├── landing-page/
│   ├── index.php
│   ├── other.build.files
└──
```

In the .htaccess files of the root, I have a setup to redirect all the requests to root/index.php preserving URL params in order to manage to the route. This is the content of my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

**THE PROBLEM:**
In this state when I try to load the path /landing-page/ it loads a blank page and in console {{index.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'}} as soon as the HTML starts. The error starts as soon as the  declaration at index.js:1, and as I click on the reference shows me the index.js of the root.
So instead of serving folder level build file, I guess it takes from the root.

**MY QUESTION IS:**

How can I keep my redirect logic at the root level while serving my static landing page from the subfolder?

The static landing page is a Svelte 3 static build, wrapped in an index.php with an `<?PHP include_once?>` that gets the index.html renamed to home.html.

This is my first question as a front-end dev after the ages of just looking at StackOverflow. Feel free to guide me incorrectly formulate questions if you feel like it.

Comment: You actually mean `/landing-page/I` with that extra `I` at the end? If not, then this request should not be affected by your rewriting to begin with - `/landing-page/` points to an existing folder, and those are excluded from your rewriting to the index.php.

Comment: Hey! @04FS sorry thats a typo, actually I see the redirect not happening when i go to /landing-page/ but still, does not load html+js. As if the index.js file is loaded from the root folder. Thanks for joining :)

Comment: Why would it load any JS resources, when you say it did not even load any HTML to begin with? What would be triggering that then?

Comment: @04FS actually, the in DevTools if i inspect i see something:
— in the DOM i see my html but clearly JS is not loaded because body tag is empty if not for the index.js script 
— REALLY STRANGE: If i click on the doctype error in console it shows me a index.js file that contains index.html of root website....


But if for example i take out the /landing-page/ folder and serve it through php -S localhost the client works perfectly

Comment: What is the actual URL of the index.js that gets requested? Sounds like that request might get rewritten, too.

Answer (score 0):

So i just found out that:

The main build script tag in the **/subfolder/index.html** had wrong relative path, so i changed :

**FROM**

```
  <script src="index.js"></script>
```

**TO**

```
<script src="/landing-page/index.js"></script>
```

FeelsBadMan i feel kinda dumb lmao i was so thrown off by this